# protractor test angular bootstrap dropdowns

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angular-bootstrap

I have an angular-bootstrap dropdown which works as expected. When I click on the dropdown button in a protractor e2e test, the dropdown does not open. I tried `browser.sleep()`, `browser.waitForAngular()`, and `browser.wait(function () {return childItem.isDisplayed();}, 1500);`. The button will be clicked (css changes), the test runner waits for some time, but the dropdown does not show up. When I try to e.g. `getText()` from the childItem, I get

> ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

How can I test angular-bootstrap dropdowns in my e2e tests?

Answer (score 2):

I made a function that waits for when it is present in the HTML and after that checks if the element is vissible. Hopefully this is a possible fix for your wait problem.

```
this.waitUntilReady = function (elm) {
        browser.wait(function () {
            return elm.isPresent();
        },10000);
        browser.wait(function () {
            return elm.isDisplayed();
        },10000);
    };
```

usage:

```
waitUntillReady(element(by.id('superId')));
```